# Can we define "Algebra of fractions" like ring/field of fractions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

According to the answers to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678745/smallest-skew-field-containing-a-non-commutative-ring#:%7E:text=Let%20R%20be%20an%20integral,containing%20R%20as%20a%20subring.), if $R$ is a ring with no zero divisors, we can define a ring of fractions of $R$ if $R$ satisfies the Ore condition and that ring will be a skew-field. What would happen if $R$ is an algebra over a field is? Say $A$ is an division algebra over a field that is not necessarily associative and may have zero divisors. Is there a condition like the Ore condition that guarantees that an algebra of fractions can be defined?

Can we not just adjust the Ore condition to make it suitable for algebras? I'm not sure if associativity and having no zero-divisors affect the fact that we can extend a ring to a ring of fractions.

Answer (score 1):

The (right or left) Ore conditions are already defined for any [multiplicative subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore_condition#Multiplicative_sets) in any ring.

Using them you can define a ring of fractions by considering the subset of regular elements, of the conditions are satisfied.

Allowing zero divisors into the set does not make any sense, because if you try to make an inverse for them, the resulting ring will collapse to zero.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful. But what do you mean that having zero divisors will collapse the algebra to zero? For example, the sedenions have inverses but also has zero divisors. Maybe you are pertaining to rings? My question is for algebras (not rings).

Comment: @morphy22 if you manage to adjoin an inverse $u$ for a zero divisor $z$, where $zb=0$ and $b\neq 0$, then $b=uzb=u0=0$, a contradiction unless the ring was the zero ring to begin with.

Comment: But algebras are not necessarily associative so $uzb$ is not really well-defined.

Comment: @morphy22 that is true, I did not go beyond associative algebras. I’ve never heard of rings of fractions outside associative algebras. I thought you were more concerned with doing something more than domains.

Comment: My concern really is for non-associative algebras that might have zero divisors.