# If $A$ is an integral domain and $B \in M_{m×n}(A)$, $C\in M_{n×m}(A)$ satisfy that $BC = I_m$, $CB = I_n$, then $n = m$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, modules

Definitions:

Let $A$ be a unitary ring and $m, n$ non-zero natural numbers. An $m \times n$ matrix over $A$ is a map $B : \{1, . . . , m\} \times \{1, . . . , n\} \rightarrow A$. We will write $(b_{ij})$ instead of $B(i, j)$ and also $B = (b_{ij})$. We will call $M_{m\times n}(A)$ the set of all $m \times n$ matrices over $A$.

The identity matrix of order $n$ is the $n\times n$ scalar matrix whose components of the main diagonal are equal to $1$. We will represent it by $I_n$.

A matrix $C \in M_n(A)$ is *regular* if it is a unit of the ring $M_n(A)$, that is, if there is a matrix $C^{-1}\in M_n(A)$ such that $CC^{−1} =C^{−1}C = I_n$.

An integral domain is a domain without zero divisors.

A division ring as a unit ring in which $1 \not= 0$ and where every non-zero element has an inverse for the product.

If $D$ is a division ring, the $D-$modules are called vector spaces

Question:

> I need to prove that if $A$ is an integral domain and $B \in M_{m×n}(A)$, $C\in M_{n×m}(A)$ satisfy that $BC = I_m$, $CB = I_n$, then $n = m$, $B$ and $C$ are regular and $C = B^{−1}$.

My attempt:

Let $K$ be the field of quotients of $A$. Then $M_{m\times n}(A)M_{n\times m}(A)$ can be considered as a subring of $M_{m}(K)$, where an element of $M_{m\times n}(A)M_{n\times m}(A)$ is $BC$ such that $B\in M_{m\times n}$ and $C\in M_{n\times m}$. I will consider that $BC=I_m$ (this is in the statement). Also, I am going to fix a basis of the $K$ vector space $K^m$ and the $K$ vector space $K^n$. Based on this prefixed base, I will build the linear applications $f:K^m\rightarrow K^n$ and $g:K^n\rightarrow K^m$ whose matrices in the associated base is $B$ and $C$ respectively. Then the matrix associated with $f\circ g$ is $I_m$ (since $BC=I_m$). So $f$ is a monomorphism. Then $\dim(K^n)\leq \dim(K^m)$ that is $n\leq m$. Repeating the same steps, but changing $n$ to $m$, we arrive at $m\leq n$, and then it follows that $n=m$. Therefore $f,g$ are isomorphisms, so $B,C$ are regular, and one is the inverse of the other by definition.

Some additional considerations:

I have defined the sub ring $M_{m\times n}(A)M_{n\times m}(A)$ because when I do the composition $f\circ g$ I get a mapping $f\circ g: K^ m\rightarrow K^m$ and the matrix associated with this composition must be an element of $M_m(K)$, and as $M_{m\times n}(A)M_{n\times m}(A) \subset M_m(K)$ , so $BC$ is a matrix that can be associated with composition functions.

I also consider that the composition $(f\circ g)(x)$ is $g(f(x))$.

EDITED:In the text it mentions that to demonstrate what I am looking at in this post, use steps similar to the following demo:

If $A$ is an integral domain and $B, C\in M_n(A)$ satisfies $BC = I_n$,
then $B$ and $C$ are regular and $C = B^{-1}$.

Demostration:

Let $K$ be the field of quotients of $A$. Then $M_n(A)$ can be considered as a subring of $M_n(K)$. Let's fix a base of space vector $K^n$ and consider the linear maps $f, g : K^n \rightarrow K^n$ whose matrices in the basis considered are $B$ and $C$ respectively. So the matrix of $f \circ g$ is $I_n$, which means that $f \circ g$ is the identity map. From here I know
it follows that $f$ is a monomorphism, so $dim Im (f) = dim K^n = n$. So
we have that $Im (f) = K^n$, then $f$ is an isomorphism and $B$ it is regular. Multiplying by $B^{−1}$ in $BC = I_n$ we obtain that $C = B^{−1}$.

Comment: I don't know whether the following will help: forget about the rings, in a field $K$ and two matrices $A,B$ in $K$,.we have rank of $AB$ is less than the rank of $A$ and rank of $B$... So if I am doing it in a field, I can use some arguments about the ranks and do the work.

Comment: Over a commutative ring, if $m\ge n$ and $I_m=BC=\pmatrix{X\\ Y}\pmatrix{Z&W} =\pmatrix{XZ&XW\\ YZ&YW} $ where $X$ and $Z$ are $n\times n$, then $XZ=I_n$. Hence $\det(X)$ is a unit, $X^{-1}=\frac{\operatorname{adj}(X)}{\det(X)}$ exists, $Z$ must be equal to $X^{-1}$ and $ZX=I_n$. But then $BC=I_m$ implies that $YZ=0$ and $XW=0$ and in turn $Y$ and $W$ are zero. Therefore $I_m=BC=\pmatrix{I_n&0\\ 0&0}$ and $m=n$.

Comment: @user1551 Thank you very much for your answer, the reason why I have tried to demonstrate it this way is because shortly before the statement of my publication in the text that I am reading it is mentioned that I use an analogy to the theorem that I have added (edited).

Comment: I believe that this is implied directly by Cauchy-Binet which is really an identity about polynomials of matrix components so holds when working over a commutative ring

Comment: @user8675309 I suspect there is a proof that generalizes to commutative rings, but it seems the level at which I'm looking at these issues is lower. For example, they mention an integral domain because their field of quotients is made up of elements that have inverses and none of their elements are divisors of $0$. Since the $K^n$ are $K-$vector spaces, then their associated matrix must be a element of $M_n(K)$, and since the elements of $M_n(A)$ can be considered as elements of $M_n(K)$ (seen as subrings), then we have the requirements to apply what the proof says.

Comment: For the case of general commutative rings, I think the case where $A$ is the zero ring (the ring where $0=1$) would be an exception -- there, $A^n$ and $A^m$ are isomorphic $A$-modules for any $n,m$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple proof for any commutative ring with identity that isn't the zero ring.

Motto: understand the Linear Algebra result by working over a field then turn it into a result about polynomials to get the result over an arbitrary commutativie ring.

$\mathbf x:=\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
\vdots \\
x_{nm}\\
x_{nm+1}\\
\vdots \\
x_{2nm}\end{bmatrix}$ and $R:= \mathbb Z\big[\mathbf x\big]$
consider $B', M' \in R^{m\times n}$
where $b_{1,1}'=x_1 \text{ ; }b_{2,1}'=x_2\text{ ; }b_{m,1}'= x_{m}\text{ ; }b_{1,2}'= x_{m+1} $ and so on and the same for $M$ except each $x_i$ index is incremented by $nm$
$C':=(M')^T$

*Suppose for contradiction* that $n\neq m$
WLOG we assume that $n\gt m$, then conclude $\det\big(C'B'\big) = 0$
*justification:*
**(i)**  $R$ is an integral domain so adjoin inverses to get a field and recognize $C'B'$ is $n\times n$ with rank $\leq m\lt n$ hence determinant is zero.  The determinant definition only requires ring operations (no division) hence   $\det\big(C'B'\big) \in R$ so conclude $\det\big(C'B'\big)=0$ when working over a ring or
**(ii)**  The determinant is zero for arbitrary substitution homomorphism $R\mapsto \mathbb C$ so by principle of permanence of identities conclude $\det\big(C'B'\big) = 0$

now consider the substitution homomorphism $\phi: R\longrightarrow R'$ where $R'$ is an arbitrary commutative ring and $x_1\mapsto b_{1,1}$ and, $x_2\mapsto b_{2,1}$ so forth to recover matrices in the original post.

$I_n = CB$
$\implies 1 $
$= \det\big(CB\big)$
$=\sum_{\sigma \in \text{Perm(n)}}\phi\big((C'B')_{\sigma(1),1}\big)\phi\big((C'B')_{\sigma(2),2}\big)\dots\phi\big((C'B')_{\sigma(n),n}\big)\cdot \phi\big(\text{sign}(\sigma)\big)$
$= \sum_{\sigma \in \text{Perm(n)}}\phi\big((C'B')_{\sigma(1),1}(C'B')_{\sigma(2),2}\dots(C'B')_{\sigma(n),n}\cdot \text{sign}(\sigma)\big)$
$= \phi\big(\sum_{\sigma \in \text{Perm(n)}}(C'B')_{\sigma(1),1}(C'B')_{\sigma(2),2}\dots(C'B')_{\sigma(n),n}\cdot \text{sign}(\sigma)\big)$
$=\phi\Big(\det\big(C'B'\big)\Big)$
$= \phi(0)$
$= 0$
conclude: $1=0$ which is a contradiction and implies $n=m$.

Answer (score 0):

The ring $A$ contains a maximal ideal $m$ (assuming $A$ is non-zero) so that $k=A/m$ is a field*. Consider the matrices $B'$ and $C'$ in $M_{m\times n}(k)$, respectively $M_{n\times m}(k)$, given by applying the homomorphism $A\rightarrow A/m$ entrywise to $B$, respectively $C$. Then $B'C'=I_m$ and $C'B'=I_m$. Since $k$ is a field, we have reduced to the case that $A$ is a field, so that now using linear algebra we can show $m=n$.

* It is common for integral domains to be assumed commutative, though I notice that you have not stated that in your definition. In that case, we can only get a maximal left or right ideal, and $A/m$ is not a ring, so the proof does not work. The proof fails as the result is not actually true unless we assume $A$ is commutative.

Extra note:

I have just seen that the OP refer's to the 'field of quotients' of the domain $A$. If your domain is not commutative, then there is no field of quotients because a field is commutative! Moreover, the domain may not be a subring of a division ring as discussed here
[Smallest skew-field containing a non-commutative ring.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678745/smallest-skew-field-containing-a-non-commutative-ring). Only what are called Ore domains will have a division ring of quotients.

Comment: If you still assume that the ring is an integral domain, then why use such a powerful result (which I think is equivalent with Zorn's lemma) and don't enlage $A$ to its field of fractions?

Comment: Why not? In any case, $A$ does not have a field of fractions if it is non-commutative, so neither works when $A$ is non-commutative.

Comment: Your reference to the non-commutative case, which is not mentioned in the question (on the contrary, the OP talks about a field of fractions), can only bring some confusion, since you actually got nothing in that case, so you could have let him know about the non-commutative case in a comment under the question. Coming back to the real deal (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain) my comment stands: you used a big gun to get a small result.

Comment: The OP never says the word commutative, and talks about division rings, hinting non-commutative rings are allowed. The ring of matrices itself is also going to be non-commutative. Regarding the use of existence of a maximal ideal, sure you can call it a big gun. I don't see the problem with that as the big gun proves a bigger result, namely that the ring $A$ can have zero-divisors.

Comment: Good. Can you provide a counterexample for non-commutative rings instead of claiming that the result does not hold in that case?

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing some definitions and seeing some examples, I think I have found the solution (it seems a bit tedious):

We set the bases $D,{D\ ^\prime}$ of the $K-$ vector spaces $K^m$ and $K^n$ respectively.

We consider the bijections $\phi_D:K^m\to K^m$ and $\phi_{D\ ^\prime}:K^n\to K^n$ that to each vector $v\in K^m,w \in K^m$ assigns its coordinates in the base $D, D\ ^\prime$ respectively.

Given the isomorphisms $M_D^{D\ ^\prime}:Hom_K(K^m,K^n)\to Mat_{m\times n}(K)$ and $M_{D\ ^\prime}^D: Hom_K(K^n,K^m)\to Mat_{n\times m}(K)$, if we consider the subrings $Mat_{m\times n}(A)$ and $Mat_{n\times m} (A)$ of $Mat_{m\times n}(K)$ and $Mat_{n\times m}(K)$ respectively, then $(M_D^{D\ ^\prime})^{-1} [Mat_{m\times n}(A)]$ is a subring of $Hom_K(K^m,K^n)$ and $(M_{D\ ^\prime}^D)^{-1}[Mat_ {n\times m}(A)]$ is a subring of $Hom_K(K^n,K^m)$ . We choose a linear mapping $f$ of the subring $(M_D^{D\ ^\prime})^{-1}[Mat_{m\times n}(A)]$ and another linear mapping $g$ of the subring $( M_{D\ ^\prime}^D)^{-1}[Mat_{n\times m}(A)]$ such that
$M_D^{D\ ^\prime}(f)M_{D\ ^\prime}^D(g)=I_m$
(it also holds that $M_D^{D\ ^\prime}(f)\in Mat_{n\times m}(A)$ and $M_{D\ ^\prime}^D(g)\in Mat_{ m\times n}(A)$)

We define the linear maps $ f:K^m\to K^n$ given by $f(v)=\phi_{D\ ^\prime}^{-1}[\phi_D(v)M_D^{D\ ^ \prime}(f)]$ and $g:K^n\to K^m$ given by $g(f(v))=\phi_{D}^{-1}[\phi_{D\ ^\prime}(f(v))M_{D\ ^\prime}^{D}(g)]=\phi_{D}^{-1}\{\phi_{D\ ^\prime}(\phi_{D\ ^\prime}^{-1}[\phi_D(v)M_D^{D\ ^\prime}(f)])M_{D\ ^\prime}^{D}(g)\}=\phi_D^{-1}\{[\phi_D(v)M_D^{D\ ^\prime}(f)]M_{D\ ^\prime}^D(g)\}=\phi_D^{-1}\{\phi_D(v)M_D^{D\ ^\prime}(f)M_{D\ ^\prime}^D(g)\}$

Since $M_D^{D\ ^\prime}(f)M_{D\ ^\prime}^D(g)=I_m$ we have $\phi_D^{-1}\{\phi_D(v)M_D^ {D\ ^\prime}(f)M_{D\ ^\prime}^D(g)\}=\phi_D^{-1}\{\phi_D(v)I_m\}=v$, but we also know that the product of the matrices $M_D^{D\ ^\prime}(f)M_{D\ ^\prime}^D(g)$ is equal to $M_D^D(f \circ g)$, so which also holds that $\phi_D^{-1}\{\phi_D(v)M_D^{D\ ^\prime}(f)M_{D\ ^\prime}^D(g)\}=\phi_D^{-1}\{\phi_D(v)M_D^D(f\circ g)\}=(f\circ g)(v)$ and since both expressions are equal, then we have $(f\circ g ) (v)=v$ from which it follows that $f$ is injective. Therefore, the dimension of the image of $f$, that is, the dimension $f[K^m]$ is less than the dimension of $K^n$, which is equivalent to saying that $m\leq n$. Changing $m$ for $n$ in all of the above mentioned, and applying the same steps, we arrive at $n\leq m$. So $m=n$, and we can apply the theorem discussed in the publication, which finally proves the theorem sought.

If anyone finds any errors please let me know.

I have used $Mat_{m\times n}(K)$ because it is the nomenclature that I normally use and in the reading that I am reviewing, it is also often called $M_{m\times n}(K)$.